# Groovy - How to periodically flush data into excel files

Tags: excel, groovy, soapui, jxl

I am writing a groovy code (inside SoapUI tool) to create excel file and periodically flush data into it.
The idea is if due to some exception/interruption the code did not complete, i should get the data in excel till the time error/issue occurred.

I am using outputStream.flush() as shown below.
Below is my sample code.

```
import jxl.*
import jxl.write.*
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

    WritableWorkbook workbook;
    WritableSheet sheet;
    try{
       log.info ("    >>    Start");
       def times;
       def currentTime = times = new Date().format("dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm-ss");  

       OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/user1/Result-"+currentTime+".xls");

       WorkbookSettings workbookSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
       workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(outputStream);

       sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample 1",0);

       for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

         Label noScenarioSetLabel1 = new Label(0, i, "NO SCENARIO SET FOR EXECUTION"); 
         sheet.addCell(noScenarioSetLabel1);

         outputStream.flush();

         Thread.sleep(1000);

        }
    workbook.write();
    workbook.close();
    log.info ("    >>    End");

}catch(Exception exp){
    log.error ("Some Exp occurred : "+exp.toString());
    workbook.write();
    workbook.close();
}
```

This is not writing data on every flush. Am i missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You're not writing any data for the stream to flush.

The Excel data is written to the output stream by the `workbook.write()` method. You're not calling that method within the for loop. So you can simply call `workbook.write()` before flushing.

## A Groovier solution

Here's a Groovier way to write your program:

```
import jxl.*
import jxl.write.*

log.info ("    >>    Start")
def times;
def currentTime = times = new Date().format("dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm-ss") 

new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/user1/Result-${currentTime}.xls").withStream {outputStream ->
   def workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(outputStream)
   def sheet = workbook.createSheet('Sample 1',0)

    0.upto(9) { 
         sheet.addCell new Label(0, it, 'NO SCENARIO SET FOR EXECUTION')  
         workbook.write()    
         outputStream.flush()        
         Thread.sleep(1000)
    }      

    workbook.write() 
    workbook.close()
    log.info ("    >>    End")
}
```

Comment: This does not resolve the issue.
Infact using `workbook.write()` before `outputStream.flush()` makes only one entry in the excel file.

Comment: Well, you were getting zero entries before right? So I was correct about adding the call to `workbook.write()`. But you have some other problem. First, make sure the loop is working as expected. Add distinct log statements within the loop one before the `Thread.sleep()` and one after.

Comment: No earlier all the entries were being written but all at the same time on calling `workbook.write()` and `workbook.close()` and this is the issue, i need entries to get written in the excel file periodically and not all at once.

Also in case of any interruption i should get the entries till that time.

The loop is working correctly. Have checked with log statements.

Comment: Interesting. I'll do some debugging on the workbook methods  tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, the problem is jexcelapi does not write to the OutputStream until the workbook is closed. workbook.write() writes to an in-memory structure. I confirmed this in the jexcelapi source code and by implementing a logging OutputStream. So, to use jexcelapi you'll have to recreate the workbook and write it all out again during each iteration. An alternative is to use Apache POI, which contains a workbook.write(OutputStream). You can see an example here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/77419/fizzbuzz-type-program-that-reads-writes-to-excel/101927#101927

Comment: thanks for the analysis. I will check apache poi and figure out how to replace existing jxl api with apache poi.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries like such (say "document builders") has in general problem with "flushing before finish".
They build multilevel structures etc, I guess, i'm almost sure, big part of building is done at closing of levels cell, row, page, sheet ...

Look at 4 level of constructor calls (opening) , theoretically flush should propagate the same level (in same or reverse order)

Intelectual exercise:
*How to flush half of row, which is formally illegal in output document, has no End Of Row? Or: how to flush row with bad cell count*

DISCLAIMER: I don't use jxl, but few other document interfaces like. During very deep structural doc in iText is almost impossible to successfully flush on exception, is has no sense.

If You have risk of exception maybe get data to simpler structure in 1st stage (classic: Map, List etc), then 2nd pass (safe) with document building?